# Wrong tomcat resource in POM.xml

Tags: java, maven, spring-mvc, tomcat, intellij-idea

I found [this tutorial](http://www.concretepage.com/spring-4/spring-4-mvc-hibernate-4-mysql-maven-crud-integration-using-annotation-and-xml-with-tomcat-8-and-spring-boot-example) but after I tried to deploy with maven (within IntelliJ) I got this error:

> [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-deploy-plugin:2.7:deploy (default-deploy) on project spring4-mvc: Deployment failed: repository element was not specified in the POM inside distributionManagement element or in -DaltDeploymentRepository=id::layout::url parameter -> [Help 1]

See also: http://pastebin.com/JLg1gQiM

What I understood from it:

The POM-element inside distributionManagement is missing. I'm not sure what exactly should I provide, since I will use it locally.

Comment: Include the information in the question.

Comment: Which maven command are you using ?

Comment: Show your `pom.xml`.

Comment: @DoNhuVy
http://pastebin.com/L2FsbUqq

Comment: I would like to run my application without manual copying anything outside - within intellij - with maven tasks

Answer (score 0):

I think you misunderstood something about `deploy`.

With the maven command `package` you are doing your build with a very local result within the `target` folder.
To use it outside of this project but inside your computer you use the command `install` to place the result within the local maven repository.
With the command `deploy` you can send the result even further, e.g. a global repository server like *Nexus*. Therefore you've to configure it within the named place, the *distributionManagement* within the pom ([usage of maven deploy](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-deploy-plugin/usage.html)).

I don't think that you need this for your local test of the tutorial, so please do it like it is written in the tutorial and use `mvn package` and just copy the war-file to your tomcat folder.

Comment: Is it possible to do this ( create the package + start the server ) within intellij with maven task?

Comment: It's definitely possible with Maven ([Tutorial](https://www.mkyong.com/maven/how-to-deploy-maven-based-war-file-to-tomcat/)). If you don't use the standard tomcat but an IntelliJ-Plugin or something like that, I don't know the details/configuration for IntelliJ.